# Design a keylogger in standard C

Tags: c, c99, c89

Can a keylogger be created using functions defined in standard C, i.e in c89 or c99, without using the API's provided by the compiler?

Comment: No, it cannot.  At most, such a program could read characters (not key presses) typed into its console.

Comment: You may be motivated to look through here... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46980/windows-keylogger-in-c

Comment: so what to do if want to create one? using c

Comment: You actually expect people to help you write a keylogger?

Answer (score 3):

The definitive answer is *no* and just assuming you want to know *why*:

C is described in terms of an *abstract machine*. Without going into much details, it's a machine that doesn't exist but any C implementation must expose the same *observable behavior* as this abstract machine. Some properties of this machine are a function calling "stack"(*) and access to a linear memory model. For *hosted environments*, add input and output streams.

Things the abstract machine notably *doesn't* include are concepts of having an operating system in place (it should be possible to implement it on as many devices as possible) or until C11, any concept of parallel execution. Even having some concrete input device like a keyboard is out of scope of the C abstract machine, it only knows about input streams, not caring where the data is coming from.

What you need for a *keylogger* is some place to *hook* your code into, this might be an OS layer for input buffering, a keyboard driver or even directly the hardware (on simple machines like an old C64, controlling IO-registers for the keyboard matrix). Whatever it is, the C abstract machine can never describe it in a platform-independent way.

Note this answer is far from complete. Just trying to give a compact explanation containing the necessary *key words* to do further research in details for anyone who is interested.

<sub>(*) this doesn't have to be a stack, it's just a common implementation.</sub>

Comment: so what to do if want to create one using C? as I saw some keyloggers in c